# Using main project classes methods within dll

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, reflection

I am wrking on a project that uses class library and I need my class communicate with host application.  how can I use main project classes methods?

I load my custom assembly using *Reflection* into the app domain.

```
private void myButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MainAppNameSpace.handeling_buttons.MethodOfClass(sender as Button);
}
```

**Update:**
My question is simple, how to use a class that comes later and doesn't exist in time of writing plugin class. my approach to this demand is define classes in external libraries that can be used by main assembly and plugins both. but I'm not sure how it would be efficient and reliable in WPF environment.

Comment: This isnt the clearest question but you can use classes from a different project by inserting them at the top of your file, e.g. Using MyProjectName;

Comment: My question is simple, how to use a class that comes later and doesn't exist in time of writing plugin class. my approach to this demand is define classes in external libraries that can be used by main assembly and plugins both. but I'm not sure how it would be efficient and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your type(class) from your application domain by this code:

```
Type objectType = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        from type in asm.GetTypes()
                        where type.IsClass && type.Name == "ClassName"
                        select type).Single();
```

And then **Invoke** your desired method. that means you should know your methods name:

```
  objectType.GetMethod("YourMethod").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type),null);
```

In a case that there is parameters to pass, you could do that by using this code:

```
 objectType.GetMethod("YourMethod").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type, "MainFunctionParameter"), new object[] { "ParameterToPass" });
```

Comment: Thank you! what if I have loaded my assembly into another domain?